# Read access to the physical path

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, iis

I have a problem with access to my site. I gave IIS full control to my program but it's still not working.

The message:

> The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify that \$ has Read access to the physical path. Then test these settings again.

I have no clue of what is wrong. I'm a newbie on IIS7, I know my website works, I have run it on another PC and it is working fine.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing wrong, the reason is that AppPool User/identity has limited privilege for security reasons and you can simply ignore this warning. An effective way to eliminate this warning is to set your application pool based on a custom user, so:

1. Go to Administrative Tools > Computer Management > Local Users and Groups > Users
2. Create a user ie. YourDomainName with a strong password, click OK
3. Double click YourDomainName to open user properties
4. On General Tab: check **User cannot change password** and **Password never expires** and clear all others
5. On Member of Tab: remove all users
6. Click OK and save
7. Go to IIS Manager > Application Pools > Your domain's specific Application Pool > Advanced Settings
8. In Identity: click to change > Custom Account > Set > Enter User credentials from step 2, click OK and exit all
9. <s>Right click on website node > Edit Permissions > Add That User and Grant **Read & Execute** - **List Folder Content** - **Read**</s>
10. Using your browser: check if website is running to verify that settings you entered are correct.
11. From IIS manager > Sites > right click on your website node > Basic Settings > click Test Settings to check if authorization succeeds.

Good luck

Comment: but then that new user wont be able to read files belonging to another user (esp temporary files used by IIS application pool)

Comment: Yes, you have to avoid whatever risks that may compromise your server and cause security vulnerabilities.